# darknet: ./src/utils.c:326: error: Assertion `0' failed. (Yolov4)

Tags: yolo, darknet

All the installation follows this website: https://robocademy.com/2020/05/01/a-gentle-introduction-to-yolo-v4-for-object-detection-in-ubuntu-20-04/

However, it doesn't work whenever I want to operate this line: ./darknet detect cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights data/person.jpg

And it always shows like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFX8t.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
./darknet detect test cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights data/person.jpg
```

You can see more command line operations here: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/#how-to-use-on-the-command-line